# Why does my SKSpriteNode slows down when it touches the boundaries?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

```
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)

let dodge = childNodeWithName(Dodge) as! SKSpriteNode
dodge.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 100.0, dy: -100))
```

When the ball touches the boundaries that I set, it slows down or it just stops moving.

Allows Rotation Unchecked, 
 Friction to 0, 
 Restitution to 1, 
 linear Damping to 0, 
Angular Damping to 0

Comment: What do you want it to do when it touches the boundary?

Comment: Can you show us how the `physicsBody` of `Dodge` is defined?

Comment: When "dodge" touches the boundary I want it to bounce back.

Comment: I added the physics body to my original question.

Comment: There is a bug with the physics world, where objects can get stuck inside of there boundaries, forcing them to be trapped,  if you increase your impulse by a multiple of 10 (so dx:1000,dy:-100)  will it bounce

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the friction to 0 on your edge based physics body? (The edge of the screen) This could be causing the problem. Even though your volume based physics body has no friction (The ball) friction will still be caused unless your edge based boundary (the edge of the screen) also has no friction set.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried applyforce instead of applyimpulse?

```
dodge.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: -100))
```

Comment: That would not matter for this question, `applyImpulse` just adds directly to the the velocity, `applyForce` does calculations during the physics phase to determine velocity